# error of TFS2015 installation:'Error 0x80073e84: Failed to execute EXE package'

Tags: windows, installation, tfs-2015

while installing TFS2015 in WS2016, the error that 'Starting Team Foundation Server configuration wizard Package failed' came. How can i deal this situation?
if i ignore it and continue configuration wizard, finally, project collection failed to configure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GIwi.png)

log:
[1ECC:2290][2018-06-18T15:31:11]e000: Error 0x80073e84: Process returned error: 0x3e84
[1ECC:2290][2018-06-18T15:31:11]e000: Error 0x80073e84: Failed to execute EXE package.
[2260:1A8C][2018-06-18T15:31:11]e000: Error 0x80073e84: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

Answer (score 0):

Just try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Disable anti-virus or anti-spyware software.
- Check windows update, install the latest patches.
- Clear `%TEMP%` folder.
- Run the installer as administrator.
- Uninstall the MS Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable (from add/remove
  programs) and then reinstall TFS.

Comment: While installing TFS2015,  the MS Visual C++ 2013 x86 Redistributable was installed. Do I still uninstall the MS Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable? Or, uninstall 2013?

Comment: @HaoXu Yes, just only try to uninstall the `MS Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable`, keep  `MS Visual C++ 2013 x86 Redistributable` there.

Comment: @HaoXu Just try to upgrade the OS with the latest patches, also try do download the a new image for the TFS installer, then try it again. If that still not work,  then I suggest you preparing a new machine and try the installation again on the new OS.